# maven-metadata.xml is not updated when deploying to nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-metadata

i am using Apache Maven 3.0
Nexus Open Source Edition, Version: 1.8.0.1

this is part of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
</plugin>

<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <name>nexus</name>
   <url>http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

it is a very simple project. when i do

```
  mvn release:prepare
  mvn release:perform
```

everything runs fine:

```
...
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) @ simple ---
[INFO] Uploading: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases/...pom
[INFO] 4 KB   
[INFO] 5 KB   
[INFO]        
[INFO] Uploaded: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases/....pom (5 KB at 1.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases/.../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 603 B   
[INFO]         
[INFO] Downloaded: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases/.../maven-metadata.xml (603 B at 1.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Uploading: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/releases/.../maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] 634 B   
[INFO]         
[INFO] Uploaded: http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/.../maven-metadata.xml (634 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
```

Now i download http://myrepo/nexus/content/repositories/.../maven-metadata.xml 
it looks like this:

```
<metadata>
<groupId>simple</groupId>
<artifactId>simple</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>0.5.8</latest>
<release>0.5.8</release>
<versions>
<version>0.5.9</version>
<version>0.1</version>
<version>0.3</version>
<version>0.4</version>
<version>0.5.1</version>
<version>0.5.2</version>
<version>0.5.3</version>
<version>0.5.4</version>
<version>0.5.5</version>
<version>0.5.6</version>
<version>0.5.7</version>
<version>0.5.8</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20110202190804</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

my latest and just released version is not marked as "latest" and "release".

Now i do "Rebuild Metadata" inside Nexus WebUI. I download metadata after this again. It looks now like this

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>0.5.9</latest>
    <release>0.5.9</release>
    <versions>
      <version>0.1</version>
      <version>0.3</version>
      <version>0.4</version>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
      <version>0.5.2</version>
      <version>0.5.3</version>

      <version>0.5.4</version>
      <version>0.5.5</version>
      <version>0.5.6</version>
      <version>0.5.7</version>
      <version>0.5.8</version>
      <version>0.5.9</version>

    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20110202191117</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

This looks like a bug in nexus or in maven? Does anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: I would suggest to discuss on Maven mailing lists.

Comment: Stackoverflow is just great for questions like this. The main reason fpr Stackoverflow is to be not subscribed on101+ mailing lists.

Comment: Yes.. that does look like a bug. Have you checked if there is on in the issue tracker about this?

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Have you heard anything from the maven guys? Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried setting `updateReleaseInfo` to true in your deploy plugin configuration?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note, I haven't tried this, just happened to have the deploy plugin docs open when I read this question and it seems reasonable.

From the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html):

```
updateReleaseInfo:
Parameter used to update the metadata to make the artifact as release.

Type: boolean
Required: No
Expression: ${updateReleaseInfo}
Default: false
```

Comment: I tried this but don-t think it's a solution. In fact this will just force `<RELEASE>` in `maven-metadata.xml` to be set to whatever version you're uploading, even if ti's ending in -SNAPSHOT. It doesn't update LATEST at all.

Comment: @Xan, I believe you would only want to use that configuration if you were actually doing a release, not for snapshot deploys.  There are 2 ways to do this; either include the config shown inside a `<profile>` that you activate for releases (e.g. `mvn -Prelease release:perform` where `-Prelease` activates the profile with ID "release".  Or, you could skip the deploy config entirely and use `mvn -DupdateReleaseInfo=true release:perform` which does the same.

Comment: I belive nobody is talking about performing a release here, the issue is why the metadata is not updated?!? I have to run a job every 30seconds on Nexus to refresh it or I can never get the LATEST artifact. In fact I implemented a job for continuous integration on Hudson to deploy the LATEST successfully built artifact. The problem is that the metadata doesn't have the LATEST tag set correctly.

Comment: @Xan I have a similar problem but thought that the issue was more with Nexus API incorrectly resolving v=LATEST. FWIW, see my post [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.maven.nexus.user/5515). No answer so far...

Comment: @Nikita I noticed that running the task to rebuild the maven metadata, the LATEST tag is updated. In your case it will become 11-SNAPSHOT. After that I bet that Nexus API will respond the way you expect. (By the way, what does it mean FWIW?)

Comment: @Xan For What It's Worth. I also noticed that running rebuild metadata fixes the issue. But that seems like a bug - just not yet clear where